# WPF C#. need simple help about progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I never used progress bar. Searched in internet but could not find something useful.
So i wanna to make progress bar like this:

[image]

which must work 10 seconds
i think it must easy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF: `IsIndeterminate`

```
progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
```

WinForms: Style `Marquee`:

```
progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

Comment: thanks for replay but progressbarStyle does not appear in my visual studio 2010. Im using WPF C# 4.0

Comment: oh in 4.0 there is no marque I used  IsIndeterminate="True" and works fine. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In WPF you'd set the IsIndeterminate property of the ProgressBar to true to get the effect you want. However, I don't think it provides a simple property for controlling the speed of it. You'd probably have to re-template the progress bar or something.